# How to change the maintenance plan owner in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have configured a maintenance plan to run every day at 7am. This has automatically created the sql agent job and schedule.

I want to change the job owner to a different user. I cannot see any UI to do this at the maintenance plan level.

I know that this can be done at the job level (by updating the job owner). This is fine and I have tested that modifying the maintenance plan's existing sub plan does not overwrite the job owner value to the maintenance plan owner. However, adding a new sub-plan creates a new job with owner set as the the maintenance plan owner.

What is the Microsoft recommendation to correctly update the maintenance plan and job owner?

Possible locations:

1. SELECT * FROM dbo.sysmaintplan_plans
2. SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysssispackages

Screenshot of a sample maintenance plan:
[image]

Comment: No, because I have read that saving the maintenance task later will reset the job owner to the maintenance task owner. Reference: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/08/20/sql-server-fix-error-the-job-failed-unable-to-determine-if-the-owner-domainuser-of-job-job_name-has-server-access/ `Since this was a maintenance plan, we can update job owner but I have seen an issue with this. It overwrites the setting when the maintenance plan is edited and saved. So, the right way to modify the owner of the maintenance plan by using T-SQL. (We are making it “sa”)`

Comment: For example - modifying the maintenance plan's existing sub plan may not overwrite the job owner. However, adding a new sub-plan will create a new job with the owner as the the maintenance plan owner. Hence the reason why I want to change the maintenance plan owner.

Comment: I don't think it's usual (though I could be mistaken) to change the owner of the Maintenance Plan itself, rather the SQL Agent Job's owner is what dictates who has the permissions to run the Job that executes the Maintenance Plan. Changing the Maintenance Plan won't affect the Job owner (as you've noted) but I'm not entirely sure I understand when you say "*adding a new sub-plan will **create a new job** with the owner as the the maintenance plan owner*". Could you possibly provide a few screenshots at least of this behavior?

Comment: @J.D. - what I mean is that - SQL server creates a new job for each maintenance plan's sub-plan. So assume you have 1 sub-plan in the maintenance plan. Now say you modify the job owner to a new user. Modifying the tasks in the sub-plan will not reset this job owner, which is great. However, suppose you add another sub-plan, then SQL server creates the new job with the owner as the maintenance plan owner. I want to prevent this because the maintenance plan owner has left the organization.

Comment: I'm not in front of a SQL Server instance at the moment, and I'm not an expert on Maintenance Plans though I do use them, but I'm having a hard time conceptualizing a sub-plan vs the main plan, which is why I think screenshots would be helpful.

Comment: Ok added a screenshot now. So maintenance plan has one or more sub-plans. It's not like main plan and sub plan are parent-child.

Comment: Is there no way to handle the situation where-in the maintenance plan owner has left the organization and the plan owner needs to be reset to a valid user so that editing the existing sub-plan or added a new sup-plan doesn't assign the maintenance plan owner as the job owner?

Answer (score 1):

> **Possible locations**
>
> 1. dbo.sysmaintplan_plans `SELECT * FROM dbo.sysmaintplan_plans`
> 2. msdb.dbo.sysssispackages `SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysssispackages`

Correct, those are the right locations, as detailed in Shashank Srivastava's [article](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/change-the-maintenance-plan-owner) on SQL Server Central detailing how to change the owner.

To summarize what he talks about there, here are the steps you would need to follow.

1. Execute the below statement to check the current details of all maintenance plan configured on your SQL Server.

```
SELECT *
FROM msdb.dbo.sysmaintplan_plans
```

2. Run the below command to update the plan owner, passing the name of the maintenance plan you want to update.

```
UPDATE msdb.dbo.sysssispackages
SET [ownersid] = suser_sid('sa')
WHERE [name] = '<Your MaintenancePlan>'
```

Comment: Changes to the plan don't revert the job owner. Did you try this?

Comment: No, I am looking for official link from Microsoft.

Comment: I get your point, but I don't fully trust that article because after changing the job owner manually, any subsequent edits of the maintenance plan does not reset the job owner.

Comment: Absolutely yes, but I don't want to play with sql server internal tables without official documentation.

Comment: How about your drop the maintenance plan, then log in with the user you want to own it and recreate it?

Comment: That's definitely an option but the maintenance plan is huge one and there's no way to script it out. So I'm documenting it and looks like I will have to re create. I was just looking for an easier solution.